# Coinbase oauth 2.0 redirect uri android

Tags: android, coinbase-api

I'm trying to setup coinbase v2 oauth authentication in my android app.
I need to setup the redirect uri so when the user authorizes the access coinbase can redirect the response to my app.

My problem here is what to use in coinbase api settings for redirect uri and what to use in my app ( intent-filters + redirect uri when sending the request )

Can anyone help me here? :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For example; Lets assume your app name is foo

Use url below on Redirect URL for Coinbase Settings

```
com.foo.fooV1://coinbase-oauth
```

And handle it in the app

At `onCreate` of Activity which you use for handling redirect urls, get Intent

```
Intent i = getIntent();

if(i != null && i.getData() != null){

   String uri = i.getData().toString();

   if (uri.contains("coinbase-oauth")){
      String[] arr = uri.split("code=");
      String code = arr[1];

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
if my app name is foo what is fooV1? the class name?

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 No. V1 is just an example. It can be com.foo.fooV1 or com.foo.fooV2 or com.foo.fooApp.. What ever you want.